# Using Python and Regex,How do you remove <sup> tags from html?

Tags: python, html, regex

Using python regex, how do i remove all  tags in html? The  tags sometimes have styling, such as below:

```
<sup style="vertical-align:top;line-height:120%;font-size:7pt">(1)</sup>
```

I would like to remove everything between and including the sup tags in a larger string of html.

Comment: what would be your end result?

Comment: Obligatory reading for OPs trying to manipulate HTML with regex: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761

Comment: I fixed my issue by converting html to string and using the following:
    re.sub(r'<sup+.*?sup>+','',string of html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use an HTML Parser instead ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3001761)). For example, [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [`unwrap()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) can handle your *beautiful sup*:

> Tag.unwrap() is the opposite of wrap(). It replaces a tag with
>   whatever’s inside that tag. It’s good for stripping out markup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <sup style="vertical-align:top;line-height:120%;font-size:7pt">(1)</sup>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for sup in soup.find_all('sup'):
    sup.unwrap()

print soup.prettify()
```

Prints:

```
<div>
(1)
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is much more effective. I appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a way of removing the tags along with the content inside them? The current solution only removes the tag.